# How do the various smalltalk VMs provide cross-platform graphics for morphic?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, morphic

For example, Pharo and Squeak are different implementations of Smalltalk. Are there specific bindings in the smalltalk VM for each platform?

Answer (score 1):

Morphic is implemented **with** Smalltalk in Pharo and Squeak. So there are no bindings to an external graphics library. Though there are some differences the basic API is the same.

- [Pharo by example, chapter 11](http://pharobyexample.org/versions/PBE1-2009-10-28.pdf)
- [Squeak by example, chapter 11](http://squeakbyexample.org//SBE.pdf)
- Squeak wiki http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/30 contains useful notes how Morphic works.

There is as well a Morphic implementation in [Cuis Smalltalk](https://github.com/Cuis-Smalltalk/Cuis-Smalltalk-Dev) which aims at a version 3 of Morphic ([more](https://github.com/Cuis-Smalltalk/Cuis-Smalltalk-Dev/blob/master/Documentation/NotesOnMorphic.md)).